# Get only children category name

Tags: categories

On a single post,  I display the post's categories like this:

```
  $categories = get_the_category($id);
```

My category hierarchy is: `cat1` parent of `cat2`, parent of `cat3`, etc.

I would like to display only children categories (from `cat2` to `catN`).
I tried to use `get_category_by_slug($id,'cat1')` with no results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific question, Try this

```
  $categories = get_the_category($id);
  foreach($categories as $category){
        if($category->parent != 0){

         // Display it here
         echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>';

        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it and let you know asap.